# How to install python's coverage module and use it from commandline in Windows

Tags: python, code-coverage, coverage.py, python-coverage

I want o learn how to use python's coverage.py module to inspect the coverage pattern of my code. I tried reading about the tool from various sources and finally installed it on my windows 7 machine using 'pip' utility. After installation, the coverage module got installed in C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages.

Now, I was reading instructions on how to use it from this page : [Author's Installation Notes](http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage/install.html). I followed the installation instructions as per given on this page. However, after I installed, I'm unsure of how to use the tool from commandline? According to author after pip install of the tool, one should be able to invoke the command

```
coverage --version
```

and expect to see some output. However, when I run this command, I get **command not found error**. According to me this is expected behavior, since coverage is just another python module (i.e. has .py extension) and not a standalone executable. So, I don't know how it can be run in a standalone fashion.

Someone please provide exact details of installation of the tool. I just need help with installation. I'll learn the CMD usage from [nedbatchelder.com's "Coverage command line usage" article](http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage/cmd.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you installed coverage, you should have gotten files you can execute directly, installed into `c:\Python27\Scripts`.  Make sure you configure your Windows environment so that that directory is on your path.  Then you'll be able to use `coverage` as a command.

If you need help completing the Python installation on Windows, here are some [detailed instructions](https://openhatch.org/wiki/Boston_Python_Workshop_6/Friday/Windows_set_up_Python).

Comment: Oh. That's just downright silly of me. Thanks Ned for your instant response. I appreciate it.

Comment: Also, congratulations on turning 0x32.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `C:\Python27\python.exe -m coverage` as a command too