# Coverage python library not found after installing

Tags: python, code-coverage

I ran the command pip install coverage and it appears to have installed correctly.

```
Frodo:Triangle567 tarikkdiry$ pip install coverage
    Collecting coverage
      Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c7/d0/337673c08f5b0cc7ada3dfe2a998ae8a97d482722045644be3d79bbcbe05/coverage-4.5.1-cp37-cp37m-macosx_10_13_x86_64.whl
    Installing collected packages: coverage
    Successfully installed coverage-4.5.1
```

However, after running coverage on one of my test files, I receive this error:

```
Frodo:Triangle567 tarikkdiry$ coverage run testtriangle.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/coverage", line 7, in <module>
    from coverage.cmdline import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'coverage.cmdline'; 'coverage' is not a package
Frodo:Triangle567 tarikkdiry$
```

I have tried uninstalling every python package and reinstalling but to no success. I have tried this on another machine and can confirm the test file is working properly.

EDIT: After running pip3 check coverage and pip3 show coverage

pip3 check coverage:

```
No broken requirements found.
```

pip3 show coverage

```
Name: coverage
Version: 4.5.1
Summary: Code coverage measurement for Python
Home-page: https://bitbucket.org/ned/coveragepy
Author: Ned Batchelder and 100 others
Author-email: ned@nedbatchelder.com
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages
Requires:
Required-by:
```

Comment: [Edit] your Question and show your Python Version and the output of `pip3 check coverage` and  `pip3 show coveragel`.

Comment: Relevant: [python-custom-module-not-found-but-already-exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51421158/python-custom-module-not-found-but-already-exists)

Comment: Do you have a file named `coverage.py` in your current directory?

Comment: @jwodder yes I do

Answer (score 4):

You should check if coverage refer to python or python3. Most likely it uses `python` to run exact tool you need. Default python version on macOS is python 2.7.

Another option is to create a virtual environment by running `python3.7 -m venv $directory` (where `$directory` contains a folder for virtual environment, you can use direct paths as you wish), then activating it by running `source $directory/bin/activate`. After doing this, you'll have no problems finding all packages you want. I personally prefer this method over installing packages into the system.

Additionally, you can install python3.7 from `MacPorts` or `Homebrew` and activate it as a default python. For many libraries you can install them using these package managers as well.

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me:

```
python -m coverage run arg1 arg2 arg3
```

Instead of what is mentioned on https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/6.0.2/

```
coverage run arg1 arg2 arg3
```

Which is similar to this answer for Windows: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36656924/264359

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this on Windows when running `pip install coverage` when using the mingw64 (bash for Windows) shell. Pip detected a linux environment and didn't include the .exe that Windows needs.

To resolve this I ran `pip uninstall coverage` then opened an administrative PowerShell prompt and ran `pip install coverage`.

Answer (score 1):

According to the comments, you have a file named `coverage.py` in your current working directory.  This file is interfering with the `coverage` command's attempts to import from `coverage.cmdline`.  You need to rename the file to something else.